# How does rake db:migrate work on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

My app just crashed after I pushed to Heroku and ran `rake db:migrate`. But the error didn't make sense...

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `email_address' for #<Invite:0x000000065fb788>):
```

...because the migration contained:

```
rename_column :invites, :email, :email_address
```

So I eventually figured out that it worked after an app restart (`heroku restart`). Good deal.

However, I'm confused about how `rake db:migrate` works now. Every single other migration picked up the corresponding model attribute without the restart.

What happens when I run `rake db:migrate` on Heroku? **What spurs the app to pickup the new model attributes and why didn't it work this time?**

Comment: I had this happen to me with Heroku once as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373039/getting-nomethoderror-undefined-method-name-for-nilnilclass-when-creating-a

Comment: Did you use "heroku run rake db:migrate" on heroku console?

Comment: I actually use use `\`rake db:migrate\`` on Heroku console, which bypasses the fact that I don't own the app and thus don't have permissions to rake normally (i.e. `heroku run rake db:migrate`). Using backticks on Heroku console to bypass permissions is a hack I figured out and I hope they don't fix. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In a new rails app you can see the following

.../config/environments/development.rb

```
# In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
# every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
# since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
config.cache_classes = false
```

.../config/environments/production.rb

```
# Code is not reloaded between requests
config.cache_classes = true
```

Comment: I don't think it would be that. Usually when you run `rake db:migrate` on Heroku it *does* pickup the changes (as OP says), regardless of what that setting is set to.

Comment: So maybe that's what causes production to reload the classes, but there's a bug where rename_column doesn't trip the setting...